# How to process multiple file in different queue with inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: xml, spring-integration

I'm using Spring 4.3.8 and Spring integration 4.3.9. I expected to process multiple files with different queue concurrently. For example, there are some files with the filename A001, A002, A003, B001, B002, B003. And I want to process Axxx and Bxxx asynchronously. After it finished to process A001 and B001, A002 and B002 would be process. Queue A and queue B will not affect each other which means A003 can be process after A002 done no matter B002 is done or not. I have no idea to do that.

What I have done is shown below.

```
    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inFiles" directory="${integration.input.folder.path}" filename-regex="^A.*\.dat$|^B.*\.tsv$"
                                      comparator="fileOrderComparator"
                                      prevent-duplicates="false" >

    <int:poller fixed-delay="10000" task-executor="taskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="5" />

</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="8" />

<int-file:outbound-gateway id="inFileProcessingGateway" directory="${integration.processing.folder.path}" request-channel="inFiles"
                           reply-channel="processFile" auto-create-directory="true" delete-source-files="true" />
```

But it will process both A001, A002, B001, B002 asynchronously and this is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this goal (although it isn’t clear yet for what reason) you definitely need to use `max-messages-per-poll` according to your parallelism requirements. After receiving each set you need to stop Channel Adapter. You can do that using `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers. After performing all those tasks would be great to collect them to identify the moment that you are ready for the next set of files to poll. And start the file reading channel Adapter again. For purpose you can use an aggregator: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

**UPDATE**

> As I don't want the process queue of Axxx and Bxxx affect each other. Maybe A002 is not finished but B002 did, B003 can start to process first and no need to wait for the A002 done. Is this possible?

Right, that's a bit different scenario and it can be done with pretty simply steps:

1. You don't use `task-executor` on the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`
2. you use `Router` as subscriber for the output channel of the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`. In this router to can check a payload for the `A` and `B` pattern. Or do the same for the via appropriate `FileHeaders.FILENAME` header. And, therefore, route `A` to one channel and `B` to another.
3. Since you can't process several `A` in parallel, you really need to use a `QueueChannel` for those two router's subscribers. The polling consumer for them should not be configured with an `ExecutorChannel` to avoid concurrent tasks for similar `A` files. `B` files will be polled from their own queue. That's how you will reach a parallelism for `A` and `B` supporting sequential process in a single queue.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As I don't want the process queue of Axxx and Bxxx affect each other. Maybe A002 is not finished but B002 did, B003 can start to process first and no need to wait for the A002 done. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but that’s different story. I’ll explain later how

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I created several inbound-channel-adapter to do so at last.